# TSNE plot having Type Error must be real number, not str

Tags: machine-learning, tsne

I kept getting this error message when i tried doing TSNE plot :TypeError: must be real number, not str. I need help seriously.
below is my code:

```
y = df_new['binary']
X = df_new.drop('binary', axis = 1)
```

```
def tsne_plot(x, y):
      
    # Setting the plotting background
    sns.set(style ="whitegrid")
      
    tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, random_state = 0)
      
    # Reducing the dimensionality of the data
    X_transformed = tsne.fit_transform(x)
  
    plt.figure(figsize =(12, 8))
      
    # Building the scatter plot
    plt.scatter(X_transformed[np.where(y == 0), 0], 
                X_transformed[np.where(y == 0), 1],
                marker ='o', color ='y', linewidth ='1',
                alpha = 0.8, label ='Normal')
    plt.scatter(X_transformed[np.where(y == 1), 0],
                X_transformed[np.where(y == 1), 1],
                marker ='o', color ='k', linewidth ='1',
                alpha = 0.8, label ='Abnormal')
  
    # Specifying the location of the legend
    plt.legend(loc ='best')
      
    # Plotting the reduced data
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

linewidth argument needs to be number, not string

Comment: I think you might be able to improve your answer by taking the [tour], reading [answer] and [edit]ing to apply your new inisghts. Have fun and welcome to StackOverflow.